# Comparing objects with IDispatch to get main frame only (BHO)

Tags: c++, bho

I don't know if anyone familiar with BHO (Browser Helper Object), but an expert in c++ can help me too.

In my BHO I want to run the OnDocumentComplete() function only on the main frame - the first container and not all the Iframes inside the current page. (an alternative is to put some code only when this is the main frame).

I can't find how to track when is it the main frame that being populated.

After searching in google I found out that each frame has "IDispatch* pDisp", and I have to compare it with a pointer to the first one.

This is the main function:

```
STDMETHODIMP Browsarity::SetSite(IUnknown* pUnkSite)
{
    if (pUnkSite != NULL)
    {
        // Cache the pointer to IWebBrowser2.
        HRESULT hr = pUnkSite->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowser2, (void **)&m_spWebBrowser);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Register to sink events from DWebBrowserEvents2.
            hr = DispEventAdvise(m_spWebBrowser);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                m_fAdvised = TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Unregister event sink.
        if (m_fAdvised)
        {
            DispEventUnadvise(m_spWebBrowser);
            m_fAdvised = FALSE;
        }

        // Release cached pointers and other resources here.
        m_spWebBrowser.Release();
    }

    // Call base class implementation.
    return IObjectWithSiteImpl<Browsarity>::SetSite(pUnkSite);
}
```

This is where I want to be aware whether its the main window(frame) or not:

```
void STDMETHODCALLTYPE Browsarity::OnDocumentComplete(IDispatch *pDisp, VARIANT *pvarURL)
{
  // as you can see, this function get the IDispatch *pDisp which is unique to every frame.
  //some code
}
```

I asked this question on Microsoft forum and I got an answer without explaining how to actually implement that: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/7c433bfa-30d7-42db-980a-70e62640184c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What jeffdav suggested is, to test wether the `pDisp` supports `IWebBrowser2` via `QueryInterface()`, and if so, to check wether it is the same object as the one you stored in `SetSite()`.
The [`QueryInterface()` rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686590(VS.85).aspx) only require that a `QI` for `IUnknown` always results in the same pointer value, so you have to additionally `QI` to `IUnknown` and compare the resulting pointers.

This would lead to something like this in `OnDocumentComplete()`:

```
IWebBrowser2* pBrowser = 0;
IUnknown *pUnk1=0, *pUnk2=0;
if(   SUCCEEDED(pDisp      ->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowser2, (void**)&pBrowser))
   && SUCCEEDED(pDisp      ->QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown,     (void**)&pUnk1))
   && SUCCEEDED(m_spBrowser->QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown,     (void**)&pUnk2))
   && (pUnk1 == pUnk2)) 
{
    // ... top-level
}
```

... or if you are using ATL (as `m_spWebBrowser` suggests):

```
CComQIPtr<IWebBrowser2> spBrowser(pDisp);
if(spBrowser && spBrowser.IsEqualObject(m_spWebBrowser)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Helped me with similar problem (i was comparing the wrong interface pointers).

IE object model is a mess...

Answer (score 1):

Notice that I did not test this, I'm only rewriting what the guy on msdn said.

In ::SetSite you get an IUnknown pointer. Call IUnknown::QueryInterface on it (just like you're already doing), but instead use IID_IDISPATCH. Save this pointer somewhere, this pointer is the top level frame.

In ::OnDocumentComplete you're getting a IDispatch pointer, compare this one to the previous saved ptr and voíla, if there is a match you're in the top level.